# In Perl, how can I match a number N and the next N characters?

Tags: regex, perl

What I'm trying to do seems deceptively simple, but I can't find a way to make it work.

I want to match a number, capture it, and then match the following N characters in the string. Naively, I thought something like this would work:

```perl
$myString = "1abc3cdf\n"; 

# Capture the number, and use a back-reference in the {} to define how many characters to match
$myString =~ s/(\d+).{\1}//g;

print $myString;
```

I expect to get `bc`, but it just returns the original string `1abc3cdf`, ie no substitution has taken place.

I tried with an extended regex (ie `s///ge`) but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Aha, I see. You said you wanted to capture, but what you really want is to delete the strings.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I said capture but I meant match-and-delete - although capture would also be of interest, in other circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the [`(??{...})` inline code](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(??%7B-code-%7D)) block:

```perl
$myString =~ s/(\d+)(??{ ".{$^N}" })//g;
```

See the [Perl demo](https://ideone.com/fyBbWr).

Here is some reference:

> This is a "postponed" regular subexpression. It behaves in exactly the same way as a `(?{ code })` code block as described above, except that its return value, rather than being assigned to `$^R`, is treated as a pattern, compiled if it's a string (or used as-is if its a qr// object), then matched as if it were inserted instead of this construct.
>
> During the matching of this sub-pattern, it has its own set of captures which are valid during the sub-match, but are discarded once control returns to the main pattern.

And here is more about the whole regex:

- `(\d+)` - Capturing group #1 that matches any one or more digits
- `(??{ ".{$^N}" })` - a code block that represents "*a "postponed" regular subexpression*" whose return value is "*treated as a pattern, compiled if it's a string*". The "*`$^N` contains whatever was matched by the most-recently closed group (submatch)*" (see the [perlre reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)). In other words, if `(\d+)` captures `45`, the `(??{ ".{$^N}" })` turns into `.{45}` and thus matches any 45 characters other than line break characters.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @Bork If you think I missed anything, please let me know.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean that you eval the string expression `".{".$^N."}"`. Can't you write `".{$^N}"` instead? Use regular interpolation?

Comment: @Bork Right, it works, too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```perl
my $out = "";
for ( $myString ) {
   /\G \D+ /xgc
      and $out .= $&;

   my ( $count ) = /\G ( \d+ ) /xagc
      or last;

   if ( length - pos < $count ) {
      warn( "Too few characters remaining" );
      last;
   }

   $out .= substr( $_, pos, $count );
   pos += $count;
}

$myString = $out;
```

This has the advantage of being validating, meaning it can detect the invalidity of the input `4abc`.

Comment: I like it - but I was writing a horrible one-liner, so for my use-case, brevity beats validity 

Comment: Yeah, just putting it out there in case it's useful to anyone.